# why i get a [object element]?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xml

Hi guys im working with Ajax and xml, and im trying to work with the flickr app [flickr](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photos.getInfo) the thing is, to get a specific element in xml document, i do it like this `var title = dataInfo.getElementsByTagName('title')[0];`
i need to get the title of the foto that i get from flickr, when i do this

```
$('#results').append("<img src ="+src+" width="+width+" height="+height+">"+title);
```

My title is `[object element]`, why it doesnt display like a title in HTML?

here is the full code:(basicly i have 3 ajax request(first to get a number of fotos, second to get the size based on the buttons on my html,third is the photo info):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var numero = 10;
    var clicked = 1;

    $("#sq").click(function(){
        clicked = 1;
    });
     $("#lg-sq").click(function(){
        clicked = 2;
    });
     $("#thumb").click(function(){
        clicked = 3;
    });
     $("#small").click(function(){
        clicked = 4;
    });
     $("#mid").click(function(){
        clicked = 5;
    });

    $("#apagar").click(function () {
        $("#results").html('');
    });

    $('#pesquisar').click(function () {
        $("#results").html('');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search',
            dataType: 'xml',
            data: {
                api_key: '2fd41b49fedfd589dc265350521ab539',
                tags: $("#tag").val(),
                format: 'rest'
            },
            success: sucessHandler,
            error: errorHandler

        });

        function sucessHandler(data) {
            $("#results").html('');
            var fotos = Array.prototype.slice.call( $(data).find("photo"));

            if ($("#numero").val() != "") {
                numero = parseInt($("#numero").val());
                console.log("entrou");
            }

            fotos.forEach(function(foto,key) {
                if(key < numero){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getSizes',
                    dataType: 'xml',
                    data: {
                        api_key: '2fd41b49fedfd589dc265350521ab539',
                        photo_id: $(foto).attr('id'),
                        format: 'rest'
                    },
                    success: function(dataSize){
                         var farmId = $(foto).attr('farm');
                         var serverId= $(foto).attr('server');
                         var Id = $(foto).attr('id');
                         var secret = $(foto).attr('secret');
                         var src = "https://farm" + farmId + ".staticflickr.com/"+ serverId +"/" + Id + "_"+secret+".jpg";

                          $.ajax({
                            url: 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getInfo',
                            dataType: 'xml',
                            data: {
                                api_key: '2fd41b49fedfd589dc265350521ab539',
                                photo_id: $(foto).attr('id'),
                                format: 'rest',
                                secret: secret
                            },
                            success: function(dataInfo){
                                 if(clicked == 1){
                              var size = dataSize.getElementsByTagName('size')[0];
                              var title = dataInfo.getElementsByTagName('title')[0];
                              console.log(title);
                              var width = $(size).attr("width");
                              var height = $(size).attr("height");
                              $('#results').append("<img src ="+src+" width="+width+" height="+height+">"+title);

                         }

                         if(clicked == 2){
                             var size = dataSize.getElementsByTagName('size')[1];
                             var width = $(size).attr("width");
                             var height = $(size).attr("height");
                              $('#results').append("<img src ="+src+" width="+width+" height="+height+">");
                         }


                         if(clicked == 3){
                             var size = dataSize.getElementsByTagName('size')[2]
                             var width = $(size).attr("width");
                             var height = $(size).attr("height");
                              $('#results').append("<img src ="+src+" width="+width+" height="+height+">");
                         }

                         if(clicked == 4){
                             var size = dataSize.getElementsByTagName('size')[3]
                             var width = $(size).attr("width");
                             var height = $(size).attr("height");
                              $('#results').append("<img src ="+src+" width="+width+" height="+height+">");
                         }

                         if(clicked == 5){
                             var size = dataSize.getElementsByTagName('size')[4]
                             var width = $(size).attr("width");
                             var height = $(size).attr("height");
                              $('#results').append("<img src ="+src+" width="+width+" height="+height+">");
                         }
                            },
                            error: function(req,status,err){

                            }
                          });  

                    },
                    error: errorSize

                });
                }
            });

                function errorSize(req, status, err) {
                    console.log("error size");
                }

        }

        function errorHandler(req, status, err) {
            console.log("fail");
        }
    });
});
```

Relevant part:

```
if(clicked == 1){
  var size = dataSize.getElementsByTagName('size')[0];
  var title = dataInfo.getElementsByTagName('title')[0];
  console.log(title);
  var width = $(size).attr("width");
  var height = $(size).attr("height");
  $('#results').append("<img src ="+src+" width="+width+"     height="+height+">"+title);
```

Comment: It's because you're appending a DOMElement, not a string. Presumably you want to access a property of the element, eg `var title = dataInfo.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerText;`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `innerText` is non-standard. Use `textContent` instead.

Comment: Also note that you can massively DRY up your code by using the `clicked` variable to access the `size` elements by index instead of having N number of duplicate `if` statements

Comment: @ScottMarcus fair point, was only for examples' sake.

Comment: true, im just starting with ajax and xml, atm im worried about getting the stuff :D

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the following.

`var title = dataInfo.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerText`;

This will provide you text of the element rather than giving you the object itself.

Comment: `innerText` is non-standard. Use `textContent` instead.

Comment: is there a way to get the title and pass it directly to the dom?